# How to extract the external JS and CSS files of a web page using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I need to dig into my web page and pull out the external CSS and JS files in order to do some comparisons for my web testing.

I've used:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor ijse_JS = iwd as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string sHtml = ijse_JS.ExecuteScript("return document.documentElement.innerHTML;").ToString();
```

I'd like the External CSS and JS files in a the form of a string for me to interrogate later.

Since this is for c#, I'd take anything that you can give, it doesn't have to be selenium, just whatever works

The central premise as to why I'm doing this is because I want to run this script on a site where I don't know what it has yet. I want to run a scan on it, make a change to something, and then do another scan and note the differences and spit it out into a spreadsheet which I can query. Right now, I have Dictionary> with key of Tag names, and the values being a collection of attributes that are useable by that tag. I have another collection full of every possible CSS property as well, and what I've been doing is running through the collection of Tags, and creating a collection of IWebElements, and then iterating through that whole collection

```
        string sCurrentTag = "";
        //iterate through a Hashset<string> of all of the possible tags for HTML (premade)
        for (int k = 0; k < HashSet_of_All_Tags.Count; k++)
        {
            //I want to find all of the instances of that specific tag now
            sCurrentTag = HashSet_of_All_Tags.ElementAt(k);
            //create a collection of IWebElement that is of every instance of the Tag that I'm looking at
            IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> iwe = iwebdriver_object.FindElements(By.TagName(sCurrentTag))
            //now run through it and get all of the styling and attribute values (if they are set)
            for(int j = 0; j < iwe; j++)
            {
                IWebElement Element_Im_Looking_At = iwe.ElementAt(j);
                //This finds the tag that I'm looking at, and then it will look at the corresponding Hashset at that spot in the dictionary
                //that holds all of the relavent attributes for that element i.e. the 'div' key will have 'align' and all global attributes
                //packed into the Hashset. If there is nothing set, then don't bother keeping it. If something is set, keep it in the format
                //of "Tag=Attribute_Value; ". I will then iterate through this string later with RegEx to get the information that I care about
                for (int i = 0; i < dsh_Tags[sEle.TagName].Count(); i++)
                {
                    //reset the strings to hold onto all of the attribute values and CSS values
                    sAttr = sStyle = "";
                    //dsh_Tags is a Dictionary<string, Hashset<string>>
                    sCurr = dsh_Tags[Element_Im_Looking_At.TagName].ElementAt(i);
                    s = Element_Im_Looking_At.GetAttribute(sCurr);
                    if (s != null && s != "")
                        sAttr += $"{sCurr}={s}; ";
                }
                //This loop iterates through all CSS properties and gets every value, and packs it into a string in the same format as the one above
                //but does it for CSS styles
                for (int i = 0; i < hs_AllCSSProp.Count(); i++)
                {
                    sCurr = hs_AllCSSProp.ElementAt(i);
                    s = Element_Im_Looking_At.GetCssValue(sCurr);
                    if (s != null && s != "")
                        sStyle += $"{sCurr}={s}; ";
                }
            }
        }
```

As you may be able to gather, there is an IMENSE amount of overhead. I've done a bunch of stuff with threads and stuff which has helped with speed, but this still takes a very long time as I have to got through the entire collection of HTML tags, and their corresponding attributes, and the entire collection of CSS properties. I do this because, again, I don't know exactly what I'm looking at initially. My plan was to make it so that I look through the CSS and JavaScript FIRST, and use regex to find all of the attributes that could change, and all of the CSS that is being altered here, and then create collections that are much much smaller to those corresponding elements, iterate through only the things that I want (which will usually only be 2 or 3 attributes and 4 or 5 css properties for each element) instead of every possible one. When I did this on a page where I knew eveything about it and what would change and only included the stuff that I care about, it increased speed by ~90%.

So this brings me to the point that I'm at now. If I could dynamically figure out what I needed to look at and then create libraries of sorts on the side for the site that I'm looking at, I could run a script that would scan all of the css, and all of the scripting ONCE, store those values, and then scan the whole page, make one change, and scan the whole page again and not the differences except this time, I would only be looking at the stuff that I need to.

Comment: better to use element vise there is method getCssValue() that fetch your css values from specified Elements.

Comment: I want to dynamically build tests, and in order to do that, I can't always know what it is that I'm looking at and what the reactions will be, so I can scan the page make a change, and then scan the page again and note the difference, but I need to have an idea of what to check. Knowing what the CSS and JS have to say will help limit the search and make this far less computationally expensive.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Rather than asking for how to solve the problem with your approach, instead outline the actual problem you are trying to solve and see if there's a better approach. Doing comparisons of CSS sounds horribly complex for just about anything you might be trying to do. What are you trying to achieve with this test?